# validator not recognising property in oneOf

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm building a schema that has a property with an enum and uses a oneOf to add properties and restrictions for each case of the enum. I'm getting an error about a missing property that is definitely not missing.

A reduced version of the schema:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "https://rc2.io/something",
"title": "Rc2 Compute Messages",

"type": "object",
  "minProperties": 2,
"properties": {
    "msg": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "the command to perform",
        "enum": ["close", "execScript"]
    },
    "argument": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "main argument for the command"
    }
},
"required": ["msg", "argument"],
"oneOf": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "argument": { "maxLength": 0 },
            "msg": { "const": "close"}
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "msg": { "const": "execScript"},
            "argument": { "minLength": 1 },
            "queryId": { "type": "number", "multipleOf": 1.0, "minimum": 1 }            },
        "required": ["queryId"]
    }
]
}
```

The json I'm trying to validate:

```
{
  "queryId:": 2,
  "argument": "testVar<-22",
  "msg": "execScript"
 }
```

The output from ajv:

```
[
{
  keyword: 'maxLength',
  dataPath: '.argument',
  schemaPath: '#/oneOf/0/properties/argument/maxLength',
  params: { limit: 0 },
  message: 'should NOT be longer than 0 characters'
},
{
  keyword: 'required',
  dataPath: '',
  schemaPath: '#/oneOf/1/required',
  params: { missingProperty: 'queryId' },
  message: "should have required property 'queryId'"
},
{
  keyword: 'oneOf',
  dataPath: '',
  schemaPath: '#/oneOf',
  params: { passingSchemas: null },
  message: 'should match exactly one schema in oneOf'
}
]
```

Why is it not recognizing queryId?

Comment: As per the below answer, looks like a typo error. Please do continue to post questions should you have any others in relation to JSON Schema =]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of this simple typo "queryId:" in your JSON data? Please note the extra colon after queryId.